# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre px, dip. dp, y sp en Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, unidades-de-medición

En [android](/questions/tagged/android) hay diferentes unidades de medición de pixeles. ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre las siguientes?

- `px`
- `dp`
- `dip`
- `sp`

Comment: La respuesta de rauk está bastante completa, yo sólo agrego un enlace a una guía para iOS y Android que me ha servido mucho a mí al desarrollar aplicaciones móviles, sobre todo a entender que es cada cosa, cuando usarla y más al tener un diseño gráfico que se va a implementar tanto en iOS como en Android. Al principio usa iOS y Mac OSX para los ejemplos pero en la segunda mitad se enfoca específicamente en Android. Espero te sirva. (Está en inglés) Enlace: [Designers Guide to DPI](http://sebastien-gabriel.com/designers-guide-to-dpi/)

Comment: En este enlace se explica como puede afectar la eleccion de DP o SP al tamaño de los textos de tu app. https://www.digitaldot.es/como-evitar-que-cambie-tamano-textos-app/

Answer (score 31, accepted):

De acuerdo con [las especificaciones de unidades y medidas de Google](https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/units-measurements.html#):

**La densidad de pixeles**

Es la cantidad de pixeles que cabe en una pulgada. Las pantallas de alta densidad tienen más pixeles por pulgada que los de baja densidad. Esto da como resultado que algunos elementos gráficos (como los botones) se vean más grandes en una pantalla de baja densidad y más pequeños en una de alta densidad.

**En `Android`:**

- `px` es un pixel.
- `dip` o `dp` son pixeles de densidad independiente (density-independent pixels).
- `sp` son pixels de escala independiente (scaleable pixels).

**Los pixeles de densidad independiente (`dp` or `dip`)**

Son unidades flexibles que se escalan a dimensiones uniformes en cualquier pantalla. Cuando desarrolle aplicaciones para `Android`, utilice `dp` para mostrar los elementos uniformemente en pantallas con diferentes densidades.

Un `dp` es igual a un pixel en una pantalla de densidad de 160. 
Para calcular `dp`:

*dp = (ancho en pixeles* * *160) / densidad de la pantalla*

**Los pixeles de escala independiente (`sp`)**

Tienen la misma función que los `dp`, pero se utilizan para las fuentes. El valor por defecto de un `sp` es el mismo que el valor por defecto de un `dp`.

La diferencia principal entre un `sp` y un `dp` es que el `sp` preserva los ajustes del usuario respecto a la fuente. Los usuarios que tengan ajustes para agrandar el texto verán que el tamaño del texto concuerda con sus preferencias.

**Como conclusión:**

- `dp` y `dip` es lo mismo y se usa para objetos tipo view (aunque también puede ser usado para texto, no se recomienda).
- `sp` se utiliza sólo para texto.

Answer (score 5):

Las 4 son unidades relacionadas a los [**pixeles**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%ADxel):

> **px**: podría mencionar que es únicamente un "píxel", pero que es un píxel, es la menor unidad homogénea en color que forma parte de una
>   imagen digital.
>
> **dp**:  La densidad de Píxeles independientes - un resumen de la unidad que se basa en la densidad física de la pantalla. Estas
>   unidades son relativas a un 160 dpi de la pantalla, por lo que un dp
>   es un píxel en una extensión de 160 dpi de la pantalla. La relación de
>   dp-a-pixel va a cambiar con la densidad de pantalla, pero no
>   necesariamente en proporción directa.
>
> **dip**: es lo mismo que dp.
>
> **sp**: Independiente de la escala de Píxeles, esto es como el dp de la unidad, pero también es escalado por el usuario tamaño de la fuente
>   preferencia. Se recomienda el uso de esta unidad al especificar los
>   tamaños de fuente, por lo que se ajustará para que tanto la densidad
>   de pantalla y la preferencia del usuario.

Revisa:

[Compatibilidad entre diferentes densidades.](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities?hl=es)

[Compatibilidad con diferentes tamaños de pantalla](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes?hl=es)